# Highcharts trying to show labels directly left of columns

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

I have this highcharts graph and i'm trying to add labels such as "Total" or "Percent" that will be displayed directly to the left of all the numbers surrounding the chart. I'm wondering if there is an elegant way to do this in highcharts to avoid using html.  It would be something like an extra column that's invisible or something.  Thanks!

[image: highcharts]

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
      "chart":{
        "renderTo":setup.renderTo, // dynamic
        "type":"column",
        "width": 400,
        "height": 150 - setup.offset, 
        "backgroundColor":"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        borderWidth:0,
        borderColor:'#fff'

      },
      "title":{
        "text":""
      },
      "legend":{
        "enabled":false
      },
      "credits":{
        "enabled":false
      },
      xAxis:[{
        categories:setup.x_mixed,
        maxZoom:5,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        labels:{
          "enabled":setup.categories_label,
          "y":16,
          "style":{
            "fontSize":13,
            "color":"#999",
            fontFamily:"'helvetica neue',helvetica",
            whiteSpace:"nowrap",
            textOverflow:"clip",
            width:"100%",
            marginTop:legendSpacing
          },
          formatter:function () {
            return this.value.split("|")[0]
          }
        },
        lineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        tickWidth:0,
        offset:0
      },{
        categories:setup.x_mixed,
        maxZoom:5,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        linkedTo: 0,
        labels:{
          "enabled":true,
          "y":16,
          "style":{
            "fontSize":10,
            "color":"#999",
            fontFamily:"'helvetica neue',helvetica",
            whiteSpace:"nowrap",
            textOverflow:"clip",
            width:"100%",
            marginTop:legendSpacing
          },
          formatter:function () {
            return this.value.split("|")[1]
          }
        },
        lineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        tickWidth:0,
        opposite: setup.categories_label,
        offset: -13 - setup.offset
      },{
        categories:setup.x_mixed,
        maxZoom:5,
        minPadding: 0.2,
        linkedTo: 0,
        labels:{
          "enabled":true,
          "y":16,
          "style":{
            "fontSize":10,
            "color":"#999",
            fontFamily:"'helvetica neue',helvetica",
            whiteSpace:"nowrap",
            textOverflow:"clip",
            width:"100%",
            marginTop:legendSpacing
          },
          formatter:function () {
            return this.value.split("|")[2]
          }
        },
        lineColor:"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        tickWidth:0,
        opposite: setup.categories_label,
        offset: - setup.offset
      }],
      "yAxis":{
        "title":{
          "text":false
        },
        "gridLineWidth":0,
        "labels":{
          "enabled":false
        },
        "lineColor":"rgba(255,255,255,0)",
        "max":setup.max_p,
        "min":2,
        reversed:setup.reversed
      },
      "plotOptions":{
        "column":{
          "color":setup.option_color,
          "shadow":false,
          "borderColor":"#fff",
          "borderWidth":0,
          groupPadding:0.07,
          pointPadding:0.01
        }
      },
      tooltip:{
        shared: true,
        backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.8)',
        style:{
          color:'#ffffff'
        },
        borderWidth:0,
        shadow:false,
        formatter:function () {
          if (navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i)) {
            var response = setup.who + " " + this.x.split("|")[0] + " Fans : " + StringHelper.numberFormat(parseInt(this.y), 'flatCommas');
            return response;
          } else {
            var response = setup.who + " " + this.x.split("|")[0] + "<br/>Fans : " + StringHelper.numberFormat(parseInt(this.y), 'flatCommas');
            return response;
          }
        }
      },
      "series":[
        {
          "name":"series",
          "data":setup.data
          //  "data": [1232, 4673, 1823, 186, 85, 15, 36]

        }
      ]

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this.

1) Use the built in labels option:  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#labels

2) Use the tickPositions property for the y axis, and format the labels as needed: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions

3) Use a scatter series with data labels.  Position the point where you need it, format the data label, set the scatter point's marker radius to 0, or color to 'rgba(255,255,255,0)'

4) use plotlines, with a width of 0, and format the label accordingly

5) use the renderer function to draw your own labels  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer

**Update:**

Most of the above options may require you to adjust your margin and or spacing settings, depending on where you place the element, as the chart does not automatically adjust for the these elements that way it does for an axis label or title.

Comment: thanks jlbriggs.  I tried the first suggestion and was able to place a label on the chart, however, when I tried to move it over by styling it with left: -30px, it pushed the label out of the chart so I couldn't see it.  Is there a fix for this? I don't want to expand the width of the chart.

Comment: Setting your marginLeft should fix that.

Comment: it turned out to be spacingLeft with your labels suggestion. Add that to the answer if you want and i'll check it off

Comment: You can use either setting depending on the exact circumstances and desired result.  the margin has worked well in my use cases.